# record single value from multidimensional array to table in yii2

Tags: php, arrays, yii2

I used yii2 framework and I tried to insert every single value from multidimensional array to record in every row `BANDWIDTH_TODAY` column.

```php
$data = Bandwidth::find()->select(['SITE_ID','BANDWIDTH_TODAY'])->all();
$id = 0;

foreach ($data as $value) {
    $value = $today_bandwidth[$id]['BANDWIDTH_TODAY'];
    $data->BANDWIDTH_TODAY = $value;
    $data->save();
    $value->delete();
    $id = $id+1;

    # code...
}
```

but it has error

```html
yii\base\ErrorException: Attempt to assign property 'BANDWIDTH_TODAY' of non-object in /var/www/html/clicknotes/controllers/BandwidthController.php:83
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/clicknotes/controllers/BandwidthController.php(83): yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleError(2, 'Attempt to assi...', '/var/www/html/c...', 83, Array)
#1 [internal function]: app\controllers\BandwidthController->actionIndex()
#2 /var/www/html/clicknotes/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 /var/www/html/clicknotes/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(157): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#4 /var/www/html/clicknotes/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(528): yii\base\Controller->runAction('', Array)
#5 /var/www/html/clicknotes/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(103): yii\base\Module->runAction('bandwidth', Array)
#6 /var/www/html/clicknotes/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#7 /var/www/html/clicknotes/web/index.php(12): yii\base\Application->run()
#8 {main}
```

Any idea to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$data = Bandwidth::find()->select(['SITE_ID','BANDWIDTH_TODAY'])->all();
$id = 0;

foreach ($data as $value) {
    $value->BANDWIDTH_TODAY = $today_bandwidth[$id]['BANDWIDTH_TODAY'];
    $value->save();
    $id = $id+1;
    # code...
}
```